# Product Attribute option values has 100's of empty option values, using Magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, option

I am using Magento 1.9.1 and facing a weird issue for long time, our attribute option values has 100's of  empty option values and the new issue is in some attributes which have more values it is not allowing to deleting the empty values similarly adding new values in those fields are also not possible.

<del>I am attaching the</del> screenshot:

[image: screen shot]

Looking for help how to remove these empty spaces, either external script or any sql query.

I also checked this link but it is not helping me :

> [Delete Empty Null Attribute Options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5963/delete-empty-null-attribute-options)

Comment: I'm guessing you have a external script filling Magento's data and that the problem starts there.

Comment: Yes, Our developers has done it and now they are now able to figure out why this blank values are creating. Even doing google is not helping, we tried the solution marked another question in my link it partially solve our problem, we can delete selected attribute white space but again they get created whenever any product get uploaded.

Comment: solved the issue at last..you were right it was the external code issue that we used and it was the issue that we are giving a empty option value to those code..so if anyone else face the same kind of issue, the first thing to check is are they giving empty option value.